# ¿Como mantener los datos y visualizar imágenes de mi aplicación laravel después de hacer docker-compose down?

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Estoy tratando de usar docker para contener mi proyecto laravel. Estoy usando la imagen laravel de bitnami https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/laravel
Todo funciona perfectamente, los 3 contenedores están elevados y conectados entre sí, pero me gustaría que al hacer "docker-compose down " y luego "docker-compose up -d" los datos no se perderían y mi app funciona Para esto he creado varios volúmenes

```
  myapp:
    container_name: wallamotop
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=daniel
      - DB_DATABASE=wallamotop
    volumes:
      - './app:/opt/bitnami/laravel' 
      - './app/entrypoint.sh:/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/entrypoint.sh'    
      - './app/storage/app/public/imagenes:/opt/bitnami/laravel/storage/app/public/imagenes' 
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - wallamotop_network
```

En entrypoint.sh ejecuto los comandos "php artisan migrate" "php artisan db:seed" y "php artisan storage:link", dentro del condicional. El script funciona bien, el problema es el volumen de la carpeta de almacenamiento y las imágenes, cuando subo imágenes a mi aplicación se me muestran, el problema es cuando hago "docker-compose down" y luego hago "docker-compose up -d" y las imágenes se eliminan, como si el volumen no almacenara los datos. Las imágenes se almacenan en: storage/app/pubic/images

archivo entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# shellcheck disable=SC1091

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail
# set -o xtrace # Uncomment this line for debugging purposes

# Load libraries
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/libbitnami.sh
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/liblog.sh
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/libos.sh

# Load Laravel environment
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel-env.sh

print_welcome_page

if [[ "$*" = *"/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/run.sh"* ]]; then
    info "** Running Laravel setup **"
    /opt/bitnami/scripts/php/setup.sh
    /opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/setup.sh
    /post-init.sh

    php artisan storage:link

    if ! docker volume inspect mariadb_data >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        info "MariaDB volume not found. Running migrations and seeders..."
        php artisan migrate --no-interaction
        php artisan db:seed --no-interaction
    else
        info "MariaDB volume found. Skipping migration and seeding..."
    fi

    info "** Laravel setup finished! **"
fi

echo ""
exec "$@"
```

archivo docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=daniel
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=wallamotop
    volumes:
      - mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb/data    

    networks:
      - wallamotop_network

  myapp:
    container_name: wallamotop
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=daniel
      - DB_DATABASE=wallamotop
    volumes:
      - './app:/opt/bitnami/laravel' 
      - './app/entrypoint.sh:/opt/bitnami/scripts/laravel/entrypoint.sh'    
      - './app/storage/app/public/imagenes:/opt/bitnami/laravel/storage/app/public/imagenes' 
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - wallamotop_network

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mariadb:db
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=daniel
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
    networks:
      - wallamotop_network

volumes:
  mariadb_data:

networks:
  wallamotop_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Para persistir los datos deberías montar un volumen externo, así al poner tu contenedor a `down` los datos se mantendrán. Saludos

Comment: I am mounting an external volume

Comment: Estás en [es.so], procura escribir en castellano, porque es el idioma oficial del sitio. Saludos

Comment: Perdón me confundí, ya estoy utilizando un volumen para gurdar las imagenes